# NodeJS Express session variable not saved when using jQuery POST

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

OK, so this questions has been asked a bunch of times and in different manners, however, none of the proposed solutions have worked for me so far. I have a very simple log-in page that passes user name and password to my server and the server authenticates the user and saves the user object in the session:

App.js:

```
var express = require('express')
              , SessionMongooseStore = require("session-mongoose")(express)
              , SessionStore = new SessionMongooseStore({
                               url: "mongodb://localhost/MySessions",
                               interval: 1200000 
                });

var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser());

app.use(express.session({
        store: SessionStore,
        cookie: {maxAge: 36000000},
        secret: 'MySecret'
    }));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-  Override, Content-Type, Accept');
   next();
});
```

Route:

```
app.post('/login',Session.LogIn);
```

Session.LogIn definition:

```
exports.LogIn = function(req,res){
    if(req.body){
       var user_name = req.body.email_address;
       var pwd = req.body.password;
       Store.getUser(user_name,pwd,function(err,user){
          if(error) { //do something } 
          else{
            //SAVING DATA TO THE SESSION
            req.session.authenticatedUser = user;
            req.session.foo = 'bar';
            req.session.save();
            var successResponse = {};
            successResponse.redirect = '/redirect';
            res.json(successResponse);
          }
       });
    }
}
```

My jQuery AJAX POST:

```
var post = $.ajax({url: '/login', 
                 type: "POST", 
                 data: querystring, 
                 xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, 
                 success: function(data) {
                    if(data.code!=200){
                        alert('Log in failed');
                    }
                    else if(data.redirect){
                        window.location = data.redirect;
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('Could not understand response from the server');
                    }
            }});
```

When I make the POST, I can see the session variables 'user' and 'foo' being set, I can print them, but when I come back to any route, the variables are undefined. Example, calling '/' after logging in:

```
 app.get('/',function(req,res){
    console.log('--------- Looking for authenticated user saved in session: ' +   req.session.authenticatedUser);
    console.log('--------- Foo: ' + req.session.foo);
    res.render('index');
 });
```

I get:

```
--------- Looking for authenticated user saved in session: undefined
--------- Foo: undefined
```

I have attempted to reproduce this using HTTP Poster add-on for FF and doing a POST, not using jQuery, and it works fine, the variables are saved in the session object. Every POST I've read talks about using

```
xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}
```

with my jQuery POST and using:

```
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

in my node js server, which I am doing as you can see from the code above, but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see the `Set-Cookie` in the response sent during `POST /login`?

Comment: I do.. Using Live HTTP headers extension, this is what I see in the response:
<br>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK<br>
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AsE8icHvNsBT4cFJCFJNoRCYG.qFzjip%2F6CIXWvcR72o3LJMZh5J%2FwyW6i%2BCUp9iqc6aU; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 13 Aug 2014 08:05:49 GMT

Answer (score 7):

By default, the `httpOnly` flag is set to to `true` in the cookie settings for `express.session` thus denying access to `xhr` requests, such as what jQuery does. You can enable it in the cookie configuration:

```
app.use(express.session({
  store: SessionStore,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 36000000,
    httpOnly: false // <- set httpOnly to false
  },
  secret: 'MySecret'
}));
```

Now your client's cookies should be accessible to the server during an ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just added httpOnly: false and left everything the same, still the same behavior...

Comment: @El Moreno: I've really been trying to reproduce this. I took the code you have and set everything up almost exactly the same (sans the mongodb store, just using default express 3 sessions). It works just fine with the `httpOnly` flag disabled. Are you absolutely sure `httpOnly` does not exist in cookie? Maybe clear your cookies for the domain this is on and try again. It might be aggressively keeping the old one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been away for the last few days. I will try clearing my cookies and if it still does not work, I will attempt to re-create the problem with the minimum set up as you have done and keep on adding code until I can reproduce the problem. I will post my findings.

Comment: OK, the mongo session store is the issue. If I remove the session store variable from the express.session object:    app.use(express.session({
        cookie: {maxAge: 36000000},
        secret: 'MySecret'
    }));
    then it works fine. (Sorry for the lack of formatting, for some reason it didn't show up formatted)

Comment: my issue solved when i turned off secure flag under cookie